# Adding to a NSString

Tags: iphone

How can I create a string that can have integers added and removed to it with a simple + or -1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. What you can do is add or subtract from a number and get the string representation when you need it:

```
int a = 30;
a++;
a--; // etc.
NSString *numberString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", a];
```

If you want to append or remove characters representing integers from the end of strings, look into the NSString class.

If you're looking for operator overloading, Objective C doesn't have it.

Comment: NSString *numberString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",a];